# How do I merge from another branch without needing to choose the merge option?

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there a simple way to get changes from another branch without needing to choose the merge option (choose existing or choose new changes)? I just want to overwrite all the changes.

I keep needing to choose the merge option (choose existing or choose new changes) for every single file that I make changes to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **--theirs** or **--ours** flag for [checkout after](https://nitaym.github.io/ourstheirs/) the merge.